# failed to resolve image name: short-name "caddy:2-alpine"

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, caddy

I get this error when running docker-compose up:

ERROR: failed to resolve image name: short-name "caddy:2-alpine" did not resolve to an alias and no unqualified-search registries are defined in "/etc/containers/registries.conf"

Here is my docker-compose.yaml file:

```
version: "3"

#networks:
# web:
#     external: true
# bridge:
#   driver: bridge

services:
     # CaddyServer reverse proxy
    caddy:
       restart: always
       image: caddy:2-alpine
       ports:
           - "443:443"
       command: caddy reverse-proxy --from https://xxxxxx.com --to http://0.0.0.0:8000
       #volumes:
       #    - /local/path/to/Caddyfile:/path/inside/continer/to/Caddyfile
       #     networks:
       #   - web
       #   - bridge

# Django web app
django:
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - "80:8000"
    depends_on:
      - pgdb
    #environment:
    #    - url=https://api.backend.example.com
    #command: "gunicorn config.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000"
    #networks:
    #   - bridge
pgdb:
    image: postgres
    container_name: pgdb
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=xxxxx
      - POSTGRES_USER=xxxx
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=xxxx
    volumes: 
      - pg-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
```

volumes:
pg-data:

Comment: Could you check if you are able to `docker pull caddy:2-alpine` in the machine? If not, can you please also share the /etc/containers/registries.conf file?

Answer (score 0):

I was Getting this error short-name "postgres" did not resolve to an alias and no unqualified-search registries are defined in "/etc/containers/registries.conf.

The problem was my docker was not properly installed

https://www.simplilearn.com/tutorials/docker-tutorial/how-to-install-docker-on-ubuntu

I followed this page and reinstalled docker.
it Solved for me.